Checking if picklist value is blank to start a flow
I'm trying to create a flow that will look to see if a picklist value field is blank. If it isn't blank then it should not update the field but if the field is blank then it is ok to the write the value to the field. I've tried multiple variations of the formula below but get the error:
Error: Field HSFE_Lead_Origin__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.
Formula Try 1:
AND(
NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(!$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c,""))),
ISCHANGED(ISPICKVAL(!$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c))
)
Formula Try 2:
AND(
NOT(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(!$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c,""))),
ISCHANGED(TEXT(!$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c))
)
Thanks in advance.

PRIORVALUE wraps around a field and will return the previous value of that field. Your syntax for PRIORVALUE is wrong, see the documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_priorvalue.htm&language=en_US&type=5

PRIORVALUE should wrap around !$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c:
PRIORVALUE(!$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c)

You can then use this inside of an ISPICKVAL statement:
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(!$Record.HSFE_Lead_Origin__c),"Value Here")

and if you need to wrap it in a NOT, AND, etc, you'd continue from there.
Always refer to the documentation to make sure your syntax is correct.
